# Make a bridge with two ports behave like a veth pair

Tags: linux-networking, bridge, linux-kernel

I have a linux bridge with two ports, namely p0 and p1, and I would like to modify the bridge behavior so that every frame showing up in one port is relayed to the other port and viceversa, i.e. the equivalent of what a veth pair would do. Note: I cannot simply use a veth pair in this case.

So far, I have tried the following with ebtables but it is not working:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -i p0 -o p1 -j ACCEPT
ebtables -A FORWARD -i p1 -o p0 -j ACCEPT
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. If you configure the MAC aging to 0 then you effectively disable the learning algorithm and every received frame is flooded to every other port, hence achieving the intended behavior in my case. The command is:

```
brctl setageing br0 0
```